# Formatting output from an array

Tags: php, arrays, phpgraphlib

I would like to create graph by PHPGraphlib using my data from database.

My problem is, that I have array in different format and PHPGraphlib doesn't read it.

PHPGraphlib reads array like this:

```
$data = array("15:01:14" => .0032, "15:05:14" => .0028, "15:10:14" => .0021, "15:15:14" => .0033, 
"15:20:14" => .0034);
```

and I create my array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$orders[] = array(
'price' => $row['price'],
'clock' => $row['clock'],
);
}

echo json_encode($orders);
```

so it looks like this:

> [{"price":"1570","clock":"14:56:02"},{"price":"1570","clock":"15:01:14"},{"price":"1571","clock":"15:11:49"}]

How can I get this same output like first one, to get PHPGraphlib read my array.

Comment: So in stead of using json_encode, just use $orders directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[$row['clock']] = $row['price'];
}
```

imp: avoid using mysql use mysqli or pdo

Comment: Still gives me:

[{"14:56:02":"1570"},{"15:01:14":"1570"}

not:

"15:01:14" => .0032, "15:05:14" => .0028

Answer (score 0):

Well it does this becaus you are using json_encode($orders).

This will convert

```
array("15:01:14" => .0032, "15:05:14" => .0028, ...
```

in

```
[{"15:01:14":".0032"},{"15:05:14":".0028"} , ...
```

since you are converting a php array to a json object. The example from Adil will create an array exactly like your $data array :) Btw if you want to implement some more security take a look at this : http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php it will prevent such ugly things like SQL-Injections ;)

Just in case you are looking for something like this:

```
$tmp = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $tmp .= '"'.$row['clock'].'" => "'.$row['price'].'",';
}

echo $tmp;
```

This will output: String "15:01:14" => ".0032", "15:05:14" => ".0028",...